# Binding script terms using Java scripting API

Tags: java, jsr223

I am new to JSR 223 (java scripting API), currently I am working on a project to reduce the complexity of writing customization script for application so we are creating an in house scripting to generate the customization script.
However it is my first approach at working with the scripting API and the closest I have to a background knowledge of API is a tutorial from javaworld.com. 
What I had like is for someone to point me to a detailed tutorial of implementing this API and including definition of script keywords and implementing them or perhaps point me to another approach at solving the above stated challenge.
I will appreciate any form of assistance. Thank you.

Comment: W3school is entry point for learning.

Comment: Pls note that this question is not related to javascript

Answer (score 0):

After much research I realized that I was not really asking my question right, what I want to develop is a DSL using java and the tool I require is ANTL.
Thanks everyone.